# Slow webgl in chrome in Linux Mint

Tags: gpu, webgl

Does webgl run extremely slow in linux?

I was running this [experiment](https://webglsamples.org/aquarium/aquarium.html) and fps never reached even 10 for 100 number of fishes.

My cpu is i5 7200U(IGPU).

Even my android phone can manage to run this at 30 fps.

Is that a problem with the drivers? And if yes, how can I fix that? I am running latest version(19.3) of linux mint.

Comment: What driver are you using? What version of Ubuntu? What graphcs card? You should put this detail into your question so it's easy for people to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 76.0.1 on Intel i7-9700K, Geforce GTX 1070, Nvidia's proprietary driver version 440.82 and kernel version 5.4.41 can do 1000 fishes with 50-60 fps on a 1024x1024 canvas. With 5000 fishes it drops to about 28 fps (with some fluctuations of a couple fps up or down occasionally).

I would guess that the main reason for the slowness you experience is your i5-7200U mobile processor with 15 W TDP is probably hitting its electrical/thermal power limits.